# How to conditionally extend schemas in zod?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

```
const schemaA = z.object({
  a: z.enum(['b', 'c']),
  b: z.number().optional(),
  c: z.boolean().transform((val)=> +val) // boolean to number (0 | 1).
})
const schemaB = z.object({
  d: z.string().refine(validator.isIpAddress)
  e: z.number()
  password: z.string(),
  passwordConfirm: z.string(),
}).refine((data)=> data.password === data.passwordConfirm, { path: ['password', 'passwordConfirm'], message: 'passwords do not match!' } )
const schemaC = z.object({
  d: z.string().refine(validator.isMacAddress)
  f: z.boolean().transform((val)=> +val) // boolean to number (0 | 1).
})
```

I want `schemaA` to include in itself `schemaB` only if the field `a` was equal to `"b"`, and only include `schemaC` if the field `a` was equal to `"c"`.

How can I achieve this in Zod?

Also, I want to make sure, that when I do `zod.infer<typeof schemaA>` to infer all the fields properly.

Also, I want to make sure I get a fully zod validation error message, not just a generic error message like *"validation error"*.